# MessagingGateway равен null

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Изучаю integration в spring boot. В книжке написано что бин шлюза должен создаваться автоматически как в spring data. Но я получаю nullPointExeception. В чем может быть проблема?

```
2022-10-11 20:48:10.461  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.r.ReactStrimingExampleApplication      : Starting ReactStrimingExampleApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 on DESKTOP-IUDA0B8 with PID 8168 (D:\Dczrjt\JAVA\java_applications\react_striming_example\target\classes started by kosav in D:\Dczrjt\JAVA\java_applications\react_striming_example)
2022-10-11 20:48:10.464  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.r.ReactStrimingExampleApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-10-11 20:48:10.819  INFO 8168 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2022-10-11 20:48:10.825  INFO 8168 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2022-10-11 20:48:10.870  INFO 8168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)2022-10-11 20:48:10.880  INFO 8168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-10-11 20:48:10.881  INFO 8168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-10-11 20:48:10.892  INFO 8168 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: public static owls_home.react_striming_example.FileWriterGateway owls_home.react_striming_example.ReactStrimingExampleApplication.fileWriter
2022-10-11 20:48:11.136  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2022-10-11 20:48:11.136  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2022-10-11 20:48:11.137  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.137  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {file:outbound-channel-adapter:fileConfig.fileWriter.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'fileWriterChannel' channel
2022-10-11 20:48:11.138  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileWriterChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2022-10-11 20:48:11.138  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'fileConfig.fileWriter.serviceActivator'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.138  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {transformer:fileConfig.upperCaseTransformer.transformer} as a subscriber to the 'textInChannel' channel
2022-10-11 20:48:11.138  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.textInChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2022-10-11 20:48:11.139  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'fileConfig.upperCaseTransformer.transformer'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.139  INFO 8168 --- [           main] ProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway : started bean 'fileWriterGateway#writeToFile(String, String)'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.140  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.s.i.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean    : started bean 'fileWriterGateway'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.151  INFO 8168 --- [           main] o.r.ReactStrimingExampleApplication      : Started ReactStrimingExampleApplication in 0.915 seconds (JVM running for 1.363)       
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "owls_home.react_striming_example.FileWriterGateway.writeToFile(String, String)" because "owls_home.react_striming_example.ReactStrimingExampleApplication.fileWriter" is null
        at owls_home.react_striming_example.ReactStrimingExampleApplication.main(ReactStrimingExampleApplication.java:26)
2022-10-11 20:48:11.160  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] ProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway : stopped bean 'fileWriterGateway#writeToFile(String, String)'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.161  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean    : stopped bean 'fileWriterGateway'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.161  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2022-10-11 20:48:11.162  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2022-10-11 20:48:11.162  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.162  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {file:outbound-channel-adapter:fileConfig.fileWriter.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'fileWriterChannel' channel
2022-10-11 20:48:11.163  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.fileWriterChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2022-10-11 20:48:11.164  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'fileConfig.fileWriter.serviceActivator'
2022-10-11 20:48:11.164  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {transformer:fileConfig.upperCaseTransformer.transformer} as a subscriber to the 'textInChannel' channel
2022-10-11 20:48:11.164  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.textInChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2022-10-11 20:48:11.164  INFO 8168 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean 'fileConfig.upperCaseTransformer.transformer'
PS D:\Dczrjt\JAVA\java_applications\react_striming_example>
```

springApplication:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactStrimingExampleApplication {
    @Autowired
    public static FileWriterGateway fileWriter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactStrimingExampleApplication.class, args);

        
        fileWriter.writeToFile("STIH.txt", "У лукоморья дуб зелёный; златая цепь на дубе том; и днём и ночью кот учёный всё ходит по цепи кругом; идёт направо — песнь заводит, налево — сказку говорит.");
    }
}
```

Бин конфигурации:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.io.File;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.file.support.FileExistsMode;
import org.springframework.integration.transformer.GenericTransformer;


@Configuration
public class FileConfig {
    
    @Bean
  @Transformer(inputChannel="textInChannel",              
               outputChannel="fileWriterChannel")
  public GenericTransformer<String, String> upperCaseTransformer() {

    return text -> text.toUpperCase();
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="fileWriterChannel")
  public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWriter() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("/tmp/sia6/files"));
    handler.setExpectReply(false);
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND);
    handler.setAppendNewLine(true);

    return handler;
  }
}
```

Бин шлюза:

```
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel="textInChannel")   // <1>
public interface FileWriterGateway {

  void writeToFile(
      @Header(FileHeaders.FILENAME) String filename,       // <2>
      String data);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой код не правильный с точки зрения жизненого цикла и Dependency Injection ожиданий:

```
@Autowired
public static FileWriterGateway fileWriter;
```

Spring не вставляет значения в статичиские поля.

Нужно изменить код на этот:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ReactStrimingExampleApplication.class, args);
ctx.getBean(FileWriterGateway.class).writeToFile(...);
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало

Comment: Иногда я делал отдельный класс, в котором внедрял в статик поле контекс, проблем не было, почему сейччас не сработало?

Comment: Я не думаю что внедрял через `@Autowired`

Comment: Я внедрял через конструктор и сейчас вспомнил об этом, спасибо